# What is the easiest way to shut down Kubeadm on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, service, systemctl

I have just installed `kubeadm, kubelet, kubectl, docker, docker-ce` on Ubuntu 22.04 and they all are working fine. I am wondering how I shut them all down without making them corrupted?

Also how can I start them all up again?

Furthermore I like to know if I shut them down and startup again whenever I want to put my Laptop on suspend? (I am using Kubernetes locally on my laptop).

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with the scenario mentioned above. I tried to check whether any option is available for kubeadm but there is no such option available, However if we are using kubeadm and the system gets restarted the cluster will become up one it got restarted provided you have used static ips for configuring the kubernetes nodes. In minikube you can use the minikube stop command for stopping your containers. For more information on the minikube stop command please go through this official [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/stop/).